# 400 Bad Request uploading a file via $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, post

I did a lot o test to upload a file via jQuery ajax, but I still having this error: **400 Bad request**.

This is my code:

```js
function createDatasetSync() {
    var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<remote API to call>',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + <myToken>);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        },
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("ERROR: " , data);
        }
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        createDatasetSync();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
            <input type="file" name="files"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have to send a .zip file to remote web service.

This is the cURL call that I'm trying to replicate:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer myTOKEN" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=@C:\myFile.zip" -F "type=image"  URL_to_call
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, `http status` of 400 indicates you attempt sending a request to the server with an incorrect payload. Can you verify what the format of `data` is? That will give you an insight to the problem and you'd be fine

Comment: I tried with different file type: .jpeg .zip .txt and I have the same error.
I need to upload a .zip file

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();   
          createDatasetSync();              
  });
```

This code does not work on submit button. Change button type attribute to `submit`

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for your response. I changed type from submit to button but i'm having the same result :( 
createDatasetSync() is called but with the same error: 400 Bad request

Comment: There is 400 (Bad Request){message: Bad request},  but if I replace into header

"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" with
 "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+data.boundary

the error message change into  {"message":"The 'type' parameter is required for this request."}